# Clear youtube embedded video "src" when other video clicked

Tags: jquery, youtube

I have 3 youtube videos on page. Page loads **img** elements with **src** "http://img.youtube.com/vi/**video_id**/maxresdefault.jpg". Then, for each thumbnail, goes youtube's **iframe** video code.

Even if I explicitly pointing **display: none** to the **iframe** element, it still loads the video, and it start playing invisible, if I set **autoplay=1**. I thought it won't load up, while it invisible, so I can show and hide videos via css calls, without javascript.

So how can I point jQuery to clear "**iframe src=**" when another thumbnail is clicked and other video will show up?

The idea is to serve only video thumbnail jpg, and play video only on explicit click on thumbnail - if other video is already playing, then it should be stopped clearing it's **src**. All videos can have different **ID**s'.

P.S. I hope you will understand my english :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.attr()` method. So you would say `$('iframe').attr('src', '');` essentially removing it.

Edit: I should also add that you can add a new URL the same way `$('iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/new-url-goes-here');` just make sure you change the iframe to whatever iframe or ID you have set

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote. This will do exactly what Marat is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if you are interested to use AngularJs then its very easy to use,

```
<iframe class="img-responsive" src="{{pdfLoc| trustThisUrl }}" ng-style="{
                height: iframeHeight * 0.75 + 'px'
            }" style="width:100%"></iframe>
```

here trustThisUrl is just filter,

```
angular.module("deck").filter('trustThisUrl', ["$sce", function ($sce) {
        return function (val) {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
        };
    }]);
```